# logstash grok error time parsing _grokparsefailure

Tags: grok

log

```
[20/02/2024:20:00:21 +0900] HELLO
```

filter

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => [ "message", "\[%{HTTPDATE:[time]}\] %{DATA:[data][word]}" ]
    remove_field => "message"
  }

  date {
    match => [ "[time]", "dd/MM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
    timezone => "Asia/Seoul"
  }
}
```

Can you help me solve this error?
This log failed in logstash with _grokparsefailure message.